# Implementing Circular Scrolling In PagerAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

I am using PagerAdapter for horizontal swiping for showing newspaper pages in my app.

Currently I want to implement the circular scrolling in this app.Right now what I have done is `whenever I am getting on last page I try to set the currentItem to first page`i.e that functionality working for last page to first page,but the problem is that how can I go to last page from first page.
Here I am pasting my code related to pagerAdapter & onPageChangeListener:-

```
    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter(awesomePager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    awesomePager.setPageMargin(10);
    awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        int lastPosition;
        float posOffset = 0;
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               viewerPage = position;
               CommonLogic.logMessage("Viewer Page:- "+ viewerPage, TAG, Log.VERBOSE);
               posOffset = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position,float positionOffset,int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0 && position != 0) {
                    lastPosition = position;
            }

            posOffset -= positionOffset;

            CommonLogic.logMessage(" Position:-  "
                                     + position + " Position Offset:- "                                     + positionOffset
                                        + " Position Offset Variable:-  "
                                        + posOffset
                                        + "  Position Offset Pixels:- "
                                        + positionOffsetPixels
                                        + " Last Position " + lastPosition,
                                        TAG, Log.VERBOSE);

                                CommonLogic.logMessage(" Last Position "
                                        + lastPosition, TAG, Log.VERBOSE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                 // To Detect the Last Page & This Sets it to first page.This working fine. 
         if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && viewerPage == (uris.size() - 1)) {
            CommonLogic.logMessage("Scroll State Changed ", TAG,Log.VERBOSE);
            postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                awesomePager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
               }
            }, 200);
        }
// I have also used this to detect whether the user is on first & try to move on last page,but it is not working well.
else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && (lastPosition == 0 || lastPosition == (uris.size() - 1)) && viewerPage == 0 && posOffset <= 0) {
                                    CommonLogic.logMessage( "Scroll State Changed ", TAG,Log.VERBOSE);
    postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         awesomePager.setCurrentItem((uris.size() - 1), true);
                }
        }, 200);
        } 
}
}
    });
```

Also the PagerAdapter i.e AwesomweAdapter in my case,is also as folllows:-

```
private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ViewPager pdfContainer;
    DocumentNewView documentNewView;
    CustomViewPager customViewPager;

    public AwesomePagerAdapter(CustomViewPager awesomePager) {
        this.customViewPager = awesomePager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return uris.size();
    }

    public DocumentNewView addViewAt(int position, DocumentNewView mainView) {
        CommonLogic.logMessage("Position of View:- " + position, TAG,
                Log.VERBOSE);
        pdfContainer.addView(mainView);
        return mainView;
    }

    /**
     * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
     * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
     * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
     * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be instantiated.
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
     *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
     *         page.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        CommonLogic
                .logMessage("Instantiate Item Called ", TAG, Log.VERBOSE);

        documentNewView = new DocumentNewView(cxt, display, customViewPager);
        documentNewView.setPdfContext(new PdfContext());
        CodecDocument codecDocument = documentNewView.open(uris
                .get(position));
        documentNewView.renderDocument(codecDocument);
        documentNewView.setMaxZoom(4f);
        documentNewView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        codecDocument = null;
        this.pdfContainer = (ViewPager) collection;
        return addViewAt(position, documentNewView);
     }

    /**
     * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
     * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
     * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be removed.
     * @param object
     *            The same object that was returned by
     *            {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        pdfContainer.removeView((DocumentNewView) view);

    }

    /**
     * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
     * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
     * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
     *            page views.
     */
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
        CommonLogic.logMessage("Finish Update Called ", TAG, Log.VERBOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        CommonLogic.logMessage("State Update Called ", TAG, Log.VERBOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((DocumentNewView) object);

    }
```

Please give me any suggestions/changes in my code (if applicable)  for it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I saw some circular list adapter in the docs ....

Comment: Which docs are you talking about is it the Android one or some else.

Answer (score 21):

I could achieve this by overriding `onPageSelected` method of `OnPageChangeListener`. Consider you have three pages in this order `A<->B<->C`. To goal is to reach `C` if we scroll right from `A` and similarly to reach `A` if we scroll left from `C`.

To do this, define your to have 5 pages (3+2), and organize the pages as follows:

**`C`**`<->A<->B<->C<->`**`A`**

Now in the `onPageSelected` method, check and if position if `0`, change it to `3` (`getCount()-2`) and if position is `4` (`getCount()-1`), change it to `1`. Make sure to use the method:

```
setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll)
```

Here is complete code for **CircularPagerAdaptor** Class :

```
package zolender.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class CircularPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int[] pageIDsArray;
    private int count;

    public CircularPagerAdapter(final ViewPager pager, int... pageIDs) {
        super();
        int actualNoOfIDs = pageIDs.length;
        count = actualNoOfIDs + 2;
        pageIDsArray = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < actualNoOfIDs; i++) {
            pageIDsArray[i + 1] = pageIDs[i];
        }
        pageIDsArray[0] = pageIDs[actualNoOfIDs - 1];
        pageIDsArray[count - 1] = pageIDs[0];

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                int pageCount = getCount();
                if (position == 0){
                    pager.setCurrentItem(pageCount-2,false);
                } else if (position == pageCount-1){
                    pager.setCurrentItem(1,false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int pageId = pageIDsArray[position];
        View view = inflater.inflate(pageId, null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
PagerAdapter adapter = new CircularPagerAdapter(myPager, new int[]{R.layout.farleft, R.layout.left, R.layout.middle, R.layout.right, R.layout.farright});
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
myPager.setCurrentItem(3);
```

Comment: hey can u please explain it in a more precise way, it tried it but didn't work out.

Comment: which part was confusing? In a nutshell, I add two dummy pages in both directions, and when they are selected, I moved the selection to its actual place.

Comment: Use onPageScrollStateChanged instead of onPageSelected for smoother scrolling animations.

`@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int pageCount = getCount();
        int currentItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentItem == 0) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageCount - 2, false);
        } else if (currentItem == pageCount - 1) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @kaupov it might be better if you could put it as an answer, so the coding style looks nicer :)

Comment: @Z0lenDer by using the above code the swipe working perfectly to the three screens,but View("onActivityCreated") for the A and C not updated Can you help me :-(

Comment: @appu bala, I have not code in Android for a while and I cannot test it now. But, I guess google should have a standard solution for this by now.

Comment: Won't this create extra indicators?

Comment: don' think so since app might have more then 3 views so should need to modify the pagerAdapter. also it will give "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method instantiateItem was not overridden"

Comment: Also after reached to no. 4 it jump directly to 1..and it look bad...can we have different solution for this.

Comment: setOnPageChangeListener has been deprected now :(

Comment: @Ravi yes but only to be replaced by addOnPageChangeListener

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I also needed a circular ViewPager. This is what I've done. I assume you get pageCount value from somewhere.

```
...
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //Gesture detection
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    pager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

    //pagelistener is just for getting selected page
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            selectedPage = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

and here is the GestureDetector.
Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/869451)

```
    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = Utils.ConvertToPixel(mContext, 50);
        int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = Utils.ConvertToPixel(mContext, 250);
        int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = Utils.ConvertToPixel(mContext, 200);

        try {

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE 
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
                    && selectedPage == (pageCount - 1)) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE 
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
                    && selectedPage == 0) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pageCount - 1);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: :- Thanks for the answer.I will try this thing out and reply you soon.

Comment: @efeyc thanks!! pager.setOnTouchListener(..) solved all my problems!

Comment: @efeyc The **MotionEvent e1 is always null in onFling()**. May be because of the view pager's own swipe implementation. Didn't you face this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [Z0lenDer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928135/1464743)'s answer, when using a regular `ViewPager` where you don't need to free the memory for each associated view, it's more efficient to store the created views rather than the layout IDs. This is necessary if wanting to get rid of any delay and flicker when the item is being switched.

There's also an issue with the animation when using `onPageSelected`, as it doesn't let the slide finish before doing the switch. The only way I found to avoid this is to only perform the switch once the scroll state has changed to `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` and just setting the current item in `onPageSelected`.

```
private int currentPage = 0;
```

...

```
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged: " + state);
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int pageCount = getCount();
                if (currentPage == 0){
                    pager.setCurrentItem(pageCount-2,false);
                } else if (currentPage == pageCount-1){
                    pager.setCurrentItem(1,false);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((ViewPager) container)
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "pos::" + position);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                            
                           int currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
                           Log.i("TAG", "currentPage::" + currentPage);
                           Log.i("TAG", "currentState::" + currentState);
                           Log.i("TAG", "previousState::" + previousState);
                           if (currentPage == 4 || currentPage == 0) {
                            previousState = currentState;
                            currentState = state;
                            if (previousState == 1 && currentState == 0) {
                             pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? 4 : 0);
                            }
                           }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1,
                            int arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        return
```

This should be placed inside

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final View container, int position) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used it this way,
fragment layouts in adapter 0>1>2>3>4>5,
0 & 5 are dummy

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);        //going to page 1;

    final int[] pagePosition = new int[1];

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pagePosition[0] = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { //state changes from 2 to 0 during a swipe

            if (state == 0 && pagePosition[0] == 0){            
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, false);
            } else if (state == 0 && pagePosition[0] == 5){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this helped

```
 private class CircularViewPagerHandler implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private int mCurrentPosition;
    private int mScrollState;
    private int mPreviousPosition;

    public CircularViewPagerHandler(final ViewPager viewPager) {
        mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        mCurrentPosition = position;
        mPreviousPosition = position-1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            setNextItemIfNeeded();
        }
        mScrollState = state;
    }


    private void setNextItemIfNeeded() {
        if (!isScrollStateSettling()) {
            handleSetNextItem();
        }
    }

    private boolean isScrollStateSettling() {
        return mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING; //indicated page is settling to it's final position
    }

    private void handleSetNextItem() {
        final int lastPosition = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
        if (mCurrentPosition == 0) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastPosition,false);
        } else if (mCurrentPosition == lastPosition) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }
}
```

It was @tobi_b's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24244144/8164116)