# How can I make viewpager loop?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want my ViewPager implementation to cycle between views instead of stopping at the last view. For example, if I have 3 views to display via a ViewPager, it should return back to the first View after the third View on fling instead of stopping at that third view. I want it to return to the first page/view when the user flings forward on the last page

Loop example;

A,B,C,D <--- A,B,C,D ---> A,B,C,D

Thanks a lot,

Mypageradapter;

```
package com.example.pictures;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;


public class MyPagerAdapter extends  PagerAdapter{

public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    View view=null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.picture1;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);         
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.picture2;   
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.picture3;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.picture4;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.picture5;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);   
        break;
    case 5:
        resId = R.layout.picture6;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context getBaseContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private PagerAdapter findViewById(int myfivepanelpager) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

public static Integer getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

OnPageChangeListener;

```
package com.example.pictures;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Pictures extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener{
SoundManager snd; 
int sound1,sound2,sound3;
View view=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picturespage);

 MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
 ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
 myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 myPager.setCurrentItem(0); 
 myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
snd = new SoundManager(this);
 sound1 = snd.load(R.raw.sound1);
 sound2 = snd.load(R.raw.sound2);
 sound3 = snd.load(R.raw.sound3);

}
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
            snd.play(sound1);
        break;
    case 1:
        snd.play(sound2);
        break;
    case 2:
            snd.play(sound3);
        break;
    case 3:
      Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 4:
       Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 5:
        Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: R u getting any errors? any problem with the above code? mention clearly.

Comment: I not getting error. My problem, does not return to the first page(If the last page).

Comment: I want to continuous loop (A,B,C,D <--- A,B,C,D ---> A,B,C,D)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766630/changing-viewpager-to-enable-infinite-page-scrolling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U need to create a circular adapter like shown there and then use that adapter as :

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

above code is copied from here [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection/938657#938657)

see following answer too:

[Implementing Circular Scrolling In PagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239056/implementing-circular-scrolling-in-pageradapter)