# Android Circular Swipe: VIEW not updated->Error on onActivityCreated()

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I refer from [Implementing Circular Scrolling In PagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239056/implementing-circular-scrolling-in-pageradapter/10928135#10928135) and created circular swipe,I have three pages A,B,C.The swipe works perfect,As mentioned in the link code `onPageSelected()` function shifted the first and last page for circular swipe, so my First and Last page Views are not get working, because the `OnActivityCreated()` not get called on those A&C pages.