# Make a loop in PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager

I want to loop my Viewpager and Im using the PagerAdapter extension. Everything I found in the net was an example with Fragments.

I want to solve this with a normal pageradapter. So When I Swipe from 1st view to left I want to be in the last View , and when I swipe from last view to right I want to change to 1st.

How can I solve this in an easy way (maybe without any libaries) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368693/how-to-do-circular-scrolling-on-viewpager

Comment: Also asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping

Comment: Im searching for an smooth solution. This 2 more layout is just a hack and not clean one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewpager's **`setCurrentItem()`** method for achieving such functionality. This method takes the position (zero-based) of the view you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/CircularViewPager
I used this library, but there some problems in it when you try to show many circular views simultaneously