# Infinite Scroll ViewPager with slide_in_left always

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scroller

I want to implement an infinite scroll viewpager so that if I have 3 fragments (A, B, C), will show A - B - C - A. The issue is that I want the swipe_in_left animation when I do setCurrentItem(0, true) after hitting the end. Right now, it cycles all the way left to position 0 and restarts the scroll from there.

Is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368693/how-to-do-circular-scrolling-on-viewpager

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately I ended up using this:

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/CircularViewPager