# How to make loop on image swipe view?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make Loop on image swipe view, this is the source image that I'm using. 
How can I continue swipe the image after the last one it turns to the beginning one. Thanks

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] mImages = new int[] {

    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3,
    R.drawable.image4,

};
```

Comment: This so post will help you start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622544/fix-the-animation-of-a-circular-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a [viewpager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)?

There are some threads on stackoverflow which explain how to do this. One of those can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188011/how-to-make-a-viewpager-loop) and I copy/pasted the code that was used there below:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int curr = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        int lastReal = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 2;
        if (curr == 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastReal, false);
        } else if (curr > lastReal) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        }
    }
}
```