# Android Fragments circular view

Tags: java, android

How can we display Fragments in a circular way?

```
List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment> ();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment1.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment2.class.getName()));

mpager = new fragmentAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager . setAdapter(mpager);
```

Comment: You might like this: [Circular ViewPager which uses FragmentPagerAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141346/circular-viewpager-which-uses-fragmentpageradapter)

Comment: can i scroll my fragments in reverse direction also?