# Best way to do fullscreen image slider in Android(like Android Gallery)

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have some (for ex: 100 to 200) images in my database which I have to show in my application using slider animation as here:

[image: fullscreen image slider]

I tried using viewpager but if I have 300 images in my database I will have to create 300 bitmap and fragments for viewpager.  It should look like how android devices show images in gallery(see above image for reference). Which is the best way to achieve this?  I also tried custom circular viewpager(it doesn't support images less than 4).

(see http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

I also tried the links from [how to create circular viewpager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465815/how-to-create-circular-viewpager) but I don't think these links will be an efficient way to do my task
(like 3 page logic)

I also have another doubt

```
 imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentvalue.getimagepath()));
```

If I use this code to set image from db to imageview can I get rid of using bitmap or does this approach also use bitmaps?

Comment: Try using Picasso library - http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 3):

I think the most efficient way is to use an AsyncTask for this. Take a look at a personal example:

```
public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private LoaderImageView loaderImageView;
        private int position;
        private ImageView image;
        private Bitmap bmd;

        public LoadImage(LoaderImageView loaderImageView, int position) {
            this.loaderImageView = loaderImageView;
            this.position = position;
            image = loaderImageView.getImageView();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loaderImageView.showProgress();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        private void setImageView(int heigthToSet, int weightToSet, int color) {
            // set the imageview to the current bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            ReceiptImageDataSource ds = ReceiptImageDataSource.getInstance();
            List<ReceiptImage> images = ds.selectReceiptImagesByReceiptID(currentReceipt.getId());
            if (images.size() > 0) {
                if (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position).getPhotoURL()) != null) {
                    if (images.size() > position) {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position).getPhotoURL());
                        image.setTag(position);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo_take_photo);
                    }
                } else {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_photo_receipt_x2);
                }
            }

            assert bitmap != null;
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.6f
            float scaleWidth = ((float) weightToSet) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) heigthToSet) / height;

            // create a matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // recreate the new Bitmap
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

            bmd = Utils.getRoundedCornerBitmap(resizedBitmap, color, 8, 0, EditReceiptActivity.this);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            int Measuredwidth;
            int Measuredheight;
            Point size = new Point();
            WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
                Measuredwidth = size.x;
                Measuredheight = size.y;
            } else {
                Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
                Measuredwidth = d.getWidth();
                Measuredheight = d.getHeight();
            }

            setImageView(Measuredheight - Utils.dpToPx(120, EditReceiptActivity.this), Measuredwidth - Utils.dpToPx(60, EditReceiptActivity.this),
                    Color.TRANSPARENT);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            loaderImageView.hideProgress();
            image.setImageBitmap(bmd);
            image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            // center the Image
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```