# how to create endless marquee of images with zoom functionality?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-animation

I have to create a screen in which multiple images will be scrolling (automatically) from right to left with following features:

I have to create a layout like this image:

[image]

- Small circles will be scrolling automatically like marquee.
- When Image would reach at center, image will be zoom by 20% than other image.
- Images would be click able, so that an operation could be performed after click.

**What I have done so far:**

I have used `ViewPager` but neither images are not scrolling automatically nor center image is zooming.

Please suggest or give some example.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on this, and found that basically Android `ViewPager` does not support such functionality. This requires you to create your own custom ViewPager.

For the scrolling, circular `ViewPager`, I suggest you to use [InfiniteViewPager](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager). For the adapter, you can try looking at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465815/how-to-create-circular-viewpager#11468306).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368693/how-to-do-circular-scrolling-on-viewpager) is some alternative, but I prefer `InfiniteViewPager`.

Comment: View pager is showing only one image on screen at a time. I need three images under big circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a CarouselView. There are several libraries available for it. You can try this one.
https://github.com/clkasd/CarouselViewProject.
To change the current item automatically, you can use setCurrentItem function with a timer.