# View the first fragment after swiping the last fragment horizontally

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-fragments

I have a project with three fragments and I can swipe the fragments horizontally using the **View Pager**.  I want to load the first fragment again after swiping the third fragment.According to my code I can only swipe until the third fragment.To view the first fragment I have to swipe backwards.

I think we have to include a logic here. As I'm new to programming it would be grate if someone can help me.

I have provided the code below.Thank you in advance for any help.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0){
    case 0:
    return new FragmentOne();

    case 1:
    return new FragmentTwo();

    case 2:
    return new FragmentThree();

    default:
        break;
     }
    return null;
   }
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
        }

   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465815/how-to-create-circular-viewpager)

Comment: Thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

```
private void scrollViewSecondViewPager() {

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (viewpagersecondcount <= 2) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewpagersecondcount);
                        viewpagersecondcount++;
                    } else {
                        viewpagersecondcount = 0;
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewpagersecondcount);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500, 3000);

}
```

call this method on an Oncreat() after 3rd once it will automatically call to first fragment.

Comment: What is viewpagersecondcount here.Can you please explain.

Comment: int viewpagersecondcount = 0;

Comment: To switch fragment maintain this varibale.