# Scroll View Pager in left-right direction infinitly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, infinite-scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am writing an application where I need to scroll in both (left and right direction) infinitely.

I checked with following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809726/2624806) and it work great but only in right side.

Is there any way to achieve left side scrolling as well.

Any suggestion here?

Comment: set initial position to Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2

Comment: u mean default current page...but then how it will help?

Comment: if your initial position is 1073741823 you can go left and left and left etc...

Comment: Did you get any solution to scroll in both direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this project](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager), I used it and it worked quite good, but in my case I had to do some other work to make things working in a correct way.