# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active at View Pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am writing an application where I using PageViewer to show infinite client using solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612049/2624806).

In my case I have to update this already added child from other event say from [onPageState][2], using following code:

```
PageFragment  scr = (PageFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(mPager.getCurrentItem());
```

but it returning IllegalStateException that say, Fragment already Active.

I checked with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612049/2624806)  but I am not getting it.

**EDIT: Fragment child add code:** 
It's at very beginning, I create first list of fragment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
            PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("page", i);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            pageList.add(fragment);
        }
```

**EDIT2:  Here the line fragment.setArguments(..) causing error, why?**

and this is adapter implementation:

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            int _pos = position % 5;

            PageFragment fragment = pageList.get(_pos);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("page", position);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MAX_CARD_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: show your code where you are adding fragment ?

Comment: @SilentKiller please check, I have updated question.

Comment: you'll find your answer here: ['Fragment already active' when setArguments() to fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194026/fragment-already-active-when-setarguments-to-fragment)