# 'Fragment already active' when setArguments() to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an `Activity` which hosts a `Fragment`.

The `Activity` layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.my.ContentFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java code of `Activity`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class ContentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //data from  previous Activity
            Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

            Fragment contentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);

            // Pass data to fragment
            /*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active*/
            contentFragment.setArguments(data);
        }
...   
}
```

I try to find the fragment in `onCreate()` of Activity, and then pass some data to it. But when I `contentFragment.setArguments(data);`, I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active`.

Then I also checked `contentFragment.getArguments()` which is null. So, why I can not set arguments to my fragment?

If it is not possible to pass bundle to fragment this way, how can I pass the bundle to fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arguments` are typically read in `Fragment.onCreate()` .. If you inflate the Fragment from xml layout, then the fragment is already added through the FragmentManager to the activity and can not take arguments anymore.

If a fragment needs arguments it is better for you to add it to the `FragmentManager` programatically and not using the xml way. I encourage you to have a look to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) doc where it is explained the correct fragment lifecycle and how to attach this fragment to the activity correctly.

Btw. you may find [FragmentArgs](https://github.com/sockeqwe/fragmentargs) useful.

Comment: Then, how can I get rid of it? I mean how can I pass Bundle data from activity to fragment??

Comment: You should use `FragmentManager` and instantiate the Fragment programmatically. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user842225 what do you mean? `DetailsFragment` is instantiated manually and added with `FragmentManager` like described in my answer. It's not in activities xml layout. So what?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FrameLayout` in your xml file instead of fragment tag.
Then just create new `Fragment` object from `onCreate()` of your activity [above] and call `fragment.setArguments(Bundle);`.

And inside `onCreate()` of Fragment class, call `getArguments()`, which will return passed `Bundle`.

It is best approach ever to pass bundle to `Fragment`.