# Creating a circular tab host in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-custom-view, tabwidget

Firstly, I would like to mention that since i am not sure of the terminology of the view that i am looking for so I shall try and explain the behaviour.

I am looking for build a screen with multiple tabs where the tab indicators do not fit all inside the screen so it is scrollable. This is fine but i want that when the scrolling happens, after the last tab indicator, the tab widget automatically shows the first tab indicator right after it. So kind of like a circular tab widget.

Could someone please give pointers on how this could be achieved in android.

Thanks, 
Sunny

Comment: Please explain yourself more clearly, perhaps with images?

Comment: So you mean that the tabs should loop? Kind of like infinite listview scrolling, but with tabs?

Comment: yes sir, they should loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, since you're not so clear...but i think you're looking for this:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
Sliding tabs like the ones in Google Play.

Comment: no this stops after reaching the last item. It should then move to the first item

Comment: I think you can do that by using this: https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager . Also, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping