# Android- Implement "Infinite" Slide Tab?

Tags: android

So I created a simple slide tab app using this reference via Android Studio: http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

The only difference between this and my app is that my app has more than 2 tabs (8). This is the link to my app via zip: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipe4zz1u3r0lnqt/App.zip?dl=0

Anyway to the question. I am interested in implementing infinite scroll like this: [ViewPager as a circular queue / wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping)
(The sliding tab continues after the end...|A|-->|B|-->|C|-->|A|-->|B|) So you can keep sliding right either in the page or in the tab.

However, I am not sure if or how it can be implemented as I am having a hard time understanding it. Any pointers/advice/clarification will be greatly appreciated as I am stuck.

Comment: when you scroll view pager, following are the method get called onPageScrolled, onPageScrolled, onPageSelected now you want it to be circular so let say you have n pages and you reach end of nth page, then simply override these method and provide necessary value to these method by having postion % n and it will work I guess