# Android: build.gradle error ("Failed to resolve")

Tags: android

So I am trying to implement the infinite scroll in the tabs like this: [ViewPager as a circular queue / wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping). This is github: https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

I am trying to add the dependencies to my build.gradle but I get an error: "Failed to resolve: com.antonyt. infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0. Do you know how I can solve this? I tried clean project and invalidate cache/restart.

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mariogp18.tanga"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
}
```

This is my other build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipe4zz1u3r0lnqt/App.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This library is not on jcenter - there is also an open ticket for this:
 https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager/issues/35

you can look here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/ - no antonyt there

you might want to use jitpack.io then

Comment: I tried adding jitpack.io and i still get the same error. I added maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in both repositories (all project and build script).