# Android ViewPager with setCurrentItem not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Trying to implement circular view pager(Pagination). In the below code snippet, the `setCurrentItem` method of the `Viewpager`is set to first position(0th index), but it always moves to the second position(1st index).

Below is the code,
**ViewPagerListener.java**

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int positionOfView, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "START of onPageScrolled");
                mPosition = positionOfView;
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "COMPLETION of onPageScrolled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "START of onPageSelected");
                //LogUtil.d(TAG, "Position :" + position + ", " + "Count of pager adapter :" + (mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1));
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "COMPLETION of onPageSelected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "START of onPageScrollStateChanged");
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && mPosition == 5) {
                    LogUtil.d(TAG, "trying to move to first");
                    currentItemInViewPager(0); //---> This is the position where I am setting the view to move back to start position(0th index) 

                }
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "COMPLETION of onPageScrollStateChanged");

            }
        });

@Override
    public void currentItemInViewPager(int index) {
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "START of currentItemInViewPager");
        if (index == 0) {
            if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_INTRO_FRAGMENT") != null) {
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "Removed");
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_INTRO_FRAGMENT")).commit();
            }
            mViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPagerAdapter = new TutorialPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "COMPLETION of currentItemInViewPager");
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing out anything

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to update your `mPosition`. It will always go to `onPageScrollStateChanged` and position will be 5 with dragging state.

Comment: Well actually he is updating mPosition in the wrong method it would seem. It should be update in the onPageSelected(int position) method. Not the onPageScrolled.

Comment: Guys, Tried with all the possible suggestions, still the result is same

Answer (score 0):

Before calling this method just call `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the animation of paging u will need to override the pager instead or using a library as:

https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Link to Reference:

[ViewPager as a circular queue / wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546224/viewpager-as-a-circular-queue-wrapping)

Comment: Can you give a solution?